# Fallback if no row is found with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a way with Sqlite (I'm using here the spellfix module but this question is general) to have:

```
SELECT word FROM myindextable WHERE word MATCH "hsqfkjsfq" AND top=1
```

return the matching word if it exists, **and returns the original word** "hsqfkjsfq" if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting exactly one row, you can  use aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(word), 'hsqfkjsfq')
FROM myindextable
WHERE word MATCH 'hsqfkjsfq' AND top = 1;
```

I think your condition is oversimplified.  With no wildcards, this is equivalent to :

```
select 'hsqfkjsfq';
```

Comment: The virtual table OP is using does approximate matching from a word list (for use as a spell checker or the like), so it's not equivalent to that simple select.

Answer (score 1):

If you never want to return more than one row from the original query, you can use a [compound query](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to add another row, which is the first row if no match was found:

```
SELECT word FROM myindextable WHERE word MATCH 'hsqfkjsfq' AND top=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'hsqfkjsfq'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Would there be a solution without repeating "hsqfkjsfq" twice in the query?

Comment: If you're using [parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam), you can use the same value for both. Or you could put the value into a CTE.

Comment: Yes @CL. I mean is it possible to do it by using it as parameter only once (and not twice) (just out of curiosity to see how succinct can sql syntax be)

Comment: I mean can we do this with only one "?" : `SELECT word FROM myindextable WHERE word MATCH '?' AND top=1
UNION ALL
SELECT '?'
LIMIT 1`

Comment: Just use `?1` in both places (and without quotes). It would be possible to move both occurrences into a CTE, but that would not be more succinct.